# IOS Swift - Connecting to AWS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, amazon-web-services

I am building an IOS app using AWS as the backend. I am calling the API using AWS Lambda. While debugging, I realized that my device is not connecting to the backend server.

How can I enable it to connect to the backend server?

Comment: Can you post a code snippet? Are you experiencing a crash when running your app? Is your app connected to the Internet?

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start would be with the AWS Amplify CLI: https://aws-amplify.github.io/

This sets up appropriate AWS backend services with best practices, including APIs for your iOS application that can connect to AWS Lambda. For instance:

```
npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli
amplify configure
amplify add api ##(select defaults, use existing schema)
amplify push
```

Now you'll have a GraphQL backend that can talk directly to DynamoDB tables with your app. You can also add a resolver in that talks to a Lambda function. Some further reading:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/building-a-client-app.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-lambda-resolvers.html